# django urls error when I import a non-itinerant object

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I can't understand why it gives me an error when importing my views.
I don't understand where the mistake is. I deleted some apps from the project and views, will it be for that?

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .views import Schede

class SchedeListView(ListView):
    model = Schede
    template_name = 'test.html'
    context_object_name = 'schede'
```

devtest urls

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .views import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="dash.html"), name="home"),

    path('test_schede/', views.SchedeListView.as_view(), name="test_schede"),

]
```

url general

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

#sitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .sitemaps import StaticViewSitemap

#pdf
from pdf.views import testPdfView 



sitemaps = {'static': StaticViewSitemap}

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('test/<id>/', testPdfView, name="test_pdf"),

    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),

    path('', include('devtest.urls'))
]
```

error

```
 C:\Users\dev\Downloads\laragon\www\scheda>python manage.py runserver
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Performing system checks...
    
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev\Downloads\laragon\bin\python\python-3.6.1\lib\site-packages
\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 600, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your imports fine? If `Schede` is a model, it should be imported from `models.py` I believe. And it's better to specify `your_app` name in imports.

```
from .views import Schede
```

maybe it should be:

```
from your_app.models import Schede
```

Another thing, are you sure this import is fine?

```
from .views import views
```

Maybe it should be like this:

```
from your_app import views
```